# grade subprojects & dependencies

Tags: gradle

This is definitely a beginner gradle question, but I just can't make it work.

I have a library and an application which depends on the library.

```
.
/ library
/ application
```

I can install the library through `gradle install` in `./library`, then have the application depend on the library through the group/name/version, and pick up the library through the `mavenLocal()` repository in the application `build.gradle`, then build the app in the `application` folder. And that works.

But I'd like to have a project, and that I could have a single command to build the application and, if needed, the library too (similar to the maven `-am` flag).

Here's what I have right now, in the parent folder, `build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: "java"
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
}

project(':application') {
  dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
  }
}
```

and in the same folder I have `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':library', ':application'
```

Again, if I go in the library folder and run `gradle install`, it works. I get the artifact in my `~/.m2`.

But now with the configuration I described, if I go in the root folder and run `gradle shadowJar`.. and the shadowJar task is present only in `application`, then gradle tries to compile the library but fails, apparently because it doesn't pick up the library dependencies.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':library:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

the errors are like, for instance:

> Task :library:compileJava FAILED
>   .../DateTimeAdapter.java:5: error: package javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters does not exist
>   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

and sure enough these are dependencies in the library/build.gradle =>

```
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.8'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8'
```

So my question is how do I specify the application dependency on library, so that I can run a single command and have maven build the library if needed, then the application.. I thought what I did would have gotten the first part through, but it fails, apparently due to library's transitive dependencies. I actually expect I need to handle a second part after that, which is how to specify the dependency in the application build.json. I may have to switch from specifying the maven group/name/version coordinates to the project name, but I didn't get that far yet.

I would definitely not want to list the library dependencies in the root gradle file: I'd like library to handle its dependencies, and application its dependencies, I'd like to keep the root gradle file small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`application` is unable to see the dependencies of `library` because you have declared the Jackson dependencies as an **implementation** detail of `library`.

What you intended to do was expose your `library` and it's dependencies as an **api** for consumers.

Dependencies declared in the **implementation** configuration can be thought of as "private" meaning consumers of your `library` should not access methods/classes that use those dependencies otherwise they will face errors like the one you are. **api** is basically the opposite of **implementation**.

The **api** configuration is available via the [`java-library`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) plugin.

Full working example for what you're trying to achieve (Kotlin DSL):

```
├── application
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── build.gradle.kts
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── library
│   └── build.gradle.kts
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

Root project `build.gradle.kts`:

```
subprojects {
    apply {
        plugin("java-library")
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

`settings.gradle.kts`:

```
rootProject.name = "example-proj"

include("application")
include("library")
```

Library `build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
    api("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.0")
    api("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0")
}
```

Application `build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":library"))

}
```

Comment: thank you! But i'm not sure that your first sentence reflects my issue. because it's in fact the `library` that doesn't build in my case. I get a `Task :library:compileJava`  failure. And the application works fine when working based on the artifact from ~/.m2, even when importing it as `implementation`.

Comment: there is another thing which I don't find in your explanation: how is `application` supposed to depend on `library`? You don't list any dependency on the library in the application build.gradle? Should the dependency go through the local maven repository (~/.m2, mavenLocal())? Or through a more "direct" dependency? I tried your setup, without specifying a dependency on library explicitely, `application` doesn't build. But then if I specify it through the local maven repo, a simple `gradle shadowJar` (only application has a shadowJar task) does NOT get the library installed in the local repo

Comment: I've updated the answer, bad copy/paste on my part sorry. But back to your first comment, are both `library` and `application` and different folders entirely? If you see in my answer, I have the folder structure which shows both `application` and `library` within the same folder.

Comment: I am sorry your answer was correct. In fact I had it already working before your answer, but I misinterpreted the error I got. The error was a "cannot find symbol" in the library. I thought it was because gradle didn't put the library dependencies in the classpath. Wrong. The issue was gradle using java11 and the library relying on jaxb, which was removed from the JDK in java11... adding to the library a dependency on jaxb fixed the issues.. Thank you!